# What is the most efficient way to convert a std::vector<T> to a .NET List<U>?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

What is the most efficient way to convert a std::vector to a .NET List?

To give some context, I am wrapping an unmanaged C++ class with C++/CLI. The C++/CLI class holds a pointer to the C++ class and I have a wrapper for each public method.

One method returns a std::vector, so in my wrapper I was going to return the .NET class List. I.e.

```
// unmanaged class
class A
{
    public:
        std::vector<int> runList();
}

// managed class
public ref class A
{
    public:
        // the below is obviously extremely inefficient
        List<UInt32> MethodA()
        {
            std::vector<unsigned int> runList = mpChannelNode->runList();
            std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator itr;

            List<UInt32> list = gcnew List<UInt32>();

            for (itr = runList.begin(); itr != runList.end(); itr++)
            {
                list.Add(*itr);
            }

            return list;
        }

    private:
        A* mpChannelNode;
}
```

How can I make this more efficient? Feel free to recommend a different return type for the .NET class. Lets assume I just need to get that vector into managed world efficiently in any shape or form.

Comment: If you're just wrapping a `vector<T>`, why not implement `IList<T>` and proxy all of the operations to the `vector`?

Comment: Hi Gabe - could you put that into an answer? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're *really* that concerned about it, use unverifiable code instead:

```
List<unsigned>^ MethodA()
{
    std::vector<unsigned> const& runList = mpChannelNode->runList();
    array<unsigned>^ ret = gcnew array<unsigned>(runList.size());
    if (runList.size())
    {
        pin_ptr<unsigned> dest = &ret[0];
        std::memcpy(dest, &runList[0], runList.size() * sizeof(unsigned));
    }
    return gcnew List<unsigned>(ret);
}
```

That said, I'd be surprised if there was a noticeable difference either way...

Comment: +1 but won't work for std::vector<string>.

Comment: @Seth : Correct, it won't, but neither will @Gabe's suggestion without running the risk of marshaling everything multiple times (which obviously will be worse than what you already have). Really, what you have right now is more-or-less ideal if you make @Marcel's suggested improvements (unless you want lazy marshaling).

Comment: How does std::memcpy compare with using Marshal.Copy from the InteropServices namespace? Would Marshal.Copy be safer and as fast?

Comment: @Seth : `Marshal::Copy` is implemented in terms of `memcpy`, so it couldn't be faster than `memcpy` and may be slightly (read: probably unnoticeably) slower since it does bounds-checking. The only real advantage it has is that your function won't me marked as `unsafe` in the IL metadata since you won't need `pin_ptr`, which may make consuming your class from other .NET languages easier.

Comment: Won't this result in two copies of the data?  The first for the memcpy and the second when the List is constructed from the array.

Comment: @MrSlippers : That sounds right; the invoked `List` constructor ends up being implemented in terms of `Array::Copy`, which is native code (for .NET Framework) and most likely boils down to another `memcpy`. So the question is whether two `memcpy`s is faster than 1 non-vectorizable, branchy copy (due to the capacity check) – I suppose there could be a difference for large collections, but I'm not inclined to measure for the sake of this answer ;-]

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with C++-CLI but one small improvement you can make is to create your list with the right capacity from the beginning.

```
List<UInt32> list = gcnew List<UInt32>(runList.size());
```

Another improvement would be to pre-increment your C++ iterator instead of post-incrementing it because currently you create an extra object for every element that is discarded immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Consider turning into the vector directly into an array .. the below will work and be valid, until you resize the vector.

```
vector<int> vec(10);
int *array = &vec[0];
```

Then, you should be able to treat that (I think -- VS not on machine) as a passed array to populate your list.

You should also create your list with a size that you expect to need -- adding one by one will be slow.

Comment: If mean to say that `int*` somehow implements `IEnumerable<int>`, or can otherwise be passed to `List<>`'s constructor, then no, that's incorrect.